# Reference a Table in a different Workbook to perform Multiple Find and Replace with Array not capturing entire table

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to modify a script I found to accommodate utilizing a table in a different workbook than the one I am running the macro through.

After struggling through getting to perform the function in the appropriate active workbooks, I finally have it making changes to the desired workbook. However, the Array I have built is only looping 3 times (43 lines total in my Table).  And I am 99% confident my UBound function is not worded properly and was hoping for some insight on how I might be able to to alter it to include all 43 lines of my table.  It is currently written to be Dynamic so that if I have to update the table, the macro would not need to be edited, but if I have to hardcode the number of rows, I am willing to do that - grudgingly.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook


 Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Drew\PracMap.xlsx")
 ThisWorkbook.Activate
 Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks("Elig.xlsx")

'Create variable to point to your table
 Set tbl = Workbooks("PracMap.xlsx").Worksheets("PracMap").ListObjects("PracMap")
'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
 Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
 myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
 fndList = 1
 rplcList = 2


'Loop through each item in Array lists
   For x = LBound(myArray, 2) To UBound(myArray, 1)
'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
  wb1.Activate
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then

        sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

     End If
   Next sht
 Next x

End Sub
```

---

When I step through the code(F8) and mouse over Ubound (myArray, 1) it returns a value "=3" which is my biggest clue as to why it's only looping 3 times. For the 3 loops it does do, What:=myArray(fndList, x) and Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x) display the appropriate first 3 row values for the respective columns. However, the loop ends after that. Also if I paste the table into the workbook on Sheet3 for example, it works and all 43 loops are performed.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: "I am 99% confident my UBound function is not worded properly"... You answered you own question there I think. What do you expect `UBound(myArray, 1)` to return? If you plug in `x` as the *second* index, you need to use `UBound` on the second dimension.

Comment: The immediate problem I see is that your loop bounds `For x = LBound(myArray, 2) To UBound(myArray, 1)` are using different dimensions of your array. Establishing your using `DataBodyRange` will give you a two dimensional array. What you're likely looking for is to use the lower bound of a single dimension to the upper bound of the same dimension. So `For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)`.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct - That was it. I had my LBound and UBounds reversed. Thanks

Comment: Now I'm having trouble with the active sheet. Are there superfluous calls to ThisWorkbook.Activate or wb1.Activate? The loop is working but it's not editing any of the cells that contain values from Column 1 of my table (to be replaced by the value in column 2).

Answer (score 0):

With help from @arcadeprecinct I was able to fix the array to read the appropriate number of loops.  I had to edit the line of code that reads

```
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
```

To

```
For Each sht In wb1.Worksheets
```

This allowed the find and replace function to make changes to the appropriate "Elig.xlsx" Workbook.  Thanks to all that helped.